Impact of enabling unity catalog for an existing metastore
We had a vendor create our data lakehouse with Databricks on AWS using an S3 bucket, and add some MSSQL databases and flat Excel files. Four workspaces were formed under this metastore and attached two to separate clusters, however, they did not enable Unity Catalog. With the newly added improvements to Databricks regarding UC, I was wondering what the impact would be to the workspaces and users if I enabled this option. Currently, Access Modes are set to No isolation shared.

Changing the data access mode from No Isolation Shared to a Unity Catalog compatible mode (e.g. Single User or Shared) by itself will not necessarily have an impact, but it could depending on other Unity Catalog resources and external locations.
Here's an example, pretend you have the following resources created currently:

[AWS] S3 Bucket my-metastore-s3-bucket
[AWS] IAM Role my-metastore-role
[UC] Storage Credential my-metastore-role-credential which allows Unity Catalog to use the IAM role my-metastore-role
[UC] External Location default-storage which points to the my-metastore-s3-bucket S3 bucket, and uses the Storage Credential my-metastore-role-credential to let UC authenticate.

Now say you have a cluster that is currently using No Isolation Shared access mode and is accessing data in the S3 bucket. That works currently due to the IAM role / instance profile you have attached the cluster in the cluster settings.
If you change the access mode to Single User or Shared, now the cluster is UC-enabled and will recognize that the S3 location you're accessing is defined in Unity Catalog as an External Location; therefore it will begin asserting that the cluster user has permission to access the data using access controls in Unity Catalog, which could result in access denied errors if you don't prepare the permissions ahead of time.
However, if you haven't created an External Location in Unity Catalog for the S3 bucket(s) being accessed, then changing the cluster access mode won't have an impact. It will still fallback to the IAM role / instance profile if you have it attached to the cluster.

Tip: if you'd like to migrate to Unity Catalog carefully and intentionally, start by identifying all the cloud storage (e.g. S3 buckets) that are used currently, then plan creation of Unity Catalog "Storage Credentials" and "External Locations" necessary to start governing those storage locations with Unity Catalog. Also check out Databricks' UCX tool for help assessing and migrating your workspaces to Unity Catalog.
